# What are camp entry times in the Stanislaus National Forest near Yosemite

Tags: camping, yosemite

We have a site booked for September in Dimond O, and are planning activities in Yosemite from that base. The recreation.gov site has times around check in and out, as well as late check in. But I'm struggling to find whether the campgrounds close at night, and if so, when. We're thinking of late-afternoon horseback rides followed by dinner in the Yosemite Valley, and want to be sure we can get back in to our campsite.

It will be our first time in Yosemite, so forgive any rookie questions, and thank you for any insight you might have.

Comment: The recreation.gov website has a telephone number for campground questions. Have you called to ask?

Comment: But then I'd have to talk to a person :D (but yes, that is a good suggestion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no check-in cut-off times. If you arrive late, simply find your site and setup.  It is possible that the campground host will pay you a visit that night and confirm your booking/identity.  If not, and if you're staying more than one night, you should make an effort to find them in the morning and let them know you've arrived before leaving the site for the day.  If you're only staying a single night then there's not even any real need to do this.

Comment: It'd be the second night so we'd already be checked in.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have checked in, you can come and go as you please, any time of day or night, for the duration of your stay (i.e. the dates you reserved).  Campgrounds don't have gates that are locked at night, or anything like that.

You may just want to leave something at your campsite while you are away, so that the camp host doesn't mistakenly think you have left early.  And if you come back late at night, be respectful of other campers who are sleeping, and try to minimize loud noise and bright lights.  Campgrounds usually have posted "quiet hours" during which you should not play music, run generators, etc.